# unable to import numpy and pandas into django

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy

may I check why am I unable to import numpy or pandas into django? it keeps giving

```
import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

The below is my code to import it. I'm importing at the views.py btw

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
import numpy as np
```

Comment: It may sound obvious, but just in case, have you installed numpy? Not part of standard python library

Comment: Are you using Anaconda package or something else?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you don't have numpy make sure you have installed [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)

Normally you would install `numpy`  like this with `pip`:

Python 2.7

`pip install numpy`

Python 3

`pip3 install numpy`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a venv and you receive an error after installing the package using pip, check the pip path you are using.

```
which pip
```

You can certainly check the package you installed

```
python -m pip freeze
```

If there is no numpy package

```
python -m pip install numpy
```